# How do I check for specific content in a p class and create an if statement based on that with javascript in an html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a text box on my web page in which the content changes when you click around on the page, and to make it so that I can easily change the content of the text I'd like to use variables so I only have to change the content of the string variables instead of digging around in the html.

So far I've managed to create the text box and make it possible to change from the first message to the second, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make an if statement to check for the presence of the second message and to display the third.

At the moment my code looks like this (with some stuff taken out, if you want to look at the full code the project is up on GitHub [here](https://github.com/EmergencyBattle/VNWebGit)).

Head:

```
<head>

<script>
        var text1 = "This is Emilia's portfolio site, where you can find her games, illustrations and interaction design projects, as well as a short bio and her contact info.";
        var text2 = "What would you like to do?";

    //set the first message the mascot character will say
    window.onload = function starting () {document.getElementById("changetext").innerHTML = "안녕하세요! Emilia is in Korea right now, but if you need help I\'m here to guide you!";
    }

    //set what will happen once you click the textbox
    function characterDialogue(){

        //if (#changetext == "안녕하세요! Emilia is in Korea right now, but if you need help I\'m here to guide you!"){
            document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = text1 ;
        //}
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Body:

```
<body onclick="characterDialogue()">

<div class="textbox">
        <div class="textboxspeechtext">
                <p id="changetext"></p>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Currently, the if statment present doesn't work at all. I haven't really done any work with javascript before so I'm having trouble understanding how you link it together with html, and any similar problems that had been solved didn't seem to be directly applicable to what I want to do. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `innerHtml` back and compare against the variables:-

```js
var text1 = "안녕하세요! Emilia is in Korea right now, but if you need help I\'m here to guide you!";
var text2 = "This is Emilia's portfolio site, where you can find her games, illustrations and interaction design projects, as well as a short bio and her contact info.";
var text3 = "What would you like to do?";

//set the first message the mascot character will say
window.onload = function starting() {
  document.getElementById("changetext").innerHTML = text1;
}

//set what will happen once you click the textbox
function characterDialogue() {
  var current = document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML;
  if (current == text1){
    document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = text2;
  }
  if (current == text2){
    document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = text3;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onclick="characterDialogue()">

  <div class="textbox">
    <div class="textboxspeechtext">
      <p id="changetext"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statement compares `"#changetext"` with the first text, this is incorrect. Instead you need to get the current content of `changetext` and compare it against `text1`.

Get the HTML content using:
`document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML`

Set the HTML content using: `document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = "New Text"`

So your IF statement should look like:

`if (document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML == text1)`